# send id value to the server from selected jquery autocomplete field

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-ui

I'm trying to send the id value from an autocomplete field... So far I have something like this in my form which lets me get the results of my query when I type something..

```
require_once("../classes/classmodels.php");

$tra=new Aggrekomodels();

if(isset($_GET['client']))
    die (json_encode($tra->get_proyectos_clientes($_REQUEST['term'])));

<form id="formempl">
    <input type="text" name="client" id="autoclient" />
    <input id="add" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Now, what I want to do is send the _id_employee_ instead of the text of the autocomplete. So far I have this in my js.

```
function autocompleteProjects(){

    $( "#autoclient" ).autocomplete({
        source: 'projects/add_projects.php?client=1'
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [autocomplete select event](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete#event-select) to parse out the ID from your JSON response and then add a hidden field to your form so that the ID is sent when the form is submitted:

```
$("#autoclient").autocomplete({
    source: 'projects/add_projects.php?client=1',
    select: function(event, ui) {
         // add hidden field with the selected item id
         $("#formempl")
              .append("<input id='employer_id' type='hidden' />").val(ui.item.id);
    }
});
```

Comment: I know is possible doing some sort of hidden input where u can store the value.. but i didnt get an example pretty much intuitive.. i need this functionality because im relating data and i do the relationships via ID

Comment: I've updated the answer after which should add a hidden field. This assumes the ID is present in your response JSON.